# Prove relation between norms

Tags: normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $\displaystyle f =\sum_{k=0}^nf_kx^k \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\deg f = n \geq 0$.

Prove $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \|f\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n+1}\|f\|_{\infty}$. I have already proved the first inequality. Now for the second I tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n|f_k|^2}\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n1^2} \geq \sum_{k=0}^n |f_k| \geq \|f\|_{\infty}$$

So: $\|f\|_2\sqrt{n+1} \geq \|f\|_{\infty}$ which is not exactly what I want to prove ...?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: On what space are we operating? How is $f$ defined?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right hand inequality can be proved without using Cauchy-Schwarz. Observe that $|f_k|^2 \leq \|f\|_\infty^2$ for every $k$ by definition of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, so we get

$$ \|f\|_2^2 = \sum_{k=0}^n |f_k|^2 \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \|f\|_\infty^2 = (n+1)\|f\|_\infty^2 $$
which gives you the desired inequality. (I am assuming you mean the $\ell_2$ norm here, not $L^2$)